# NLTK - missing stop words - English

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I just downloaded the latest NLTK version with all its resources.

I see `could` and `would` are not listed as stop words. 
But `should` is treated as a stop word.

Is this some kind of known bug or ... ?

```
In [7]: import nltk

In [8]: "shouldn't" in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
Out[8]: True

In [9]: "couldn't" in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
Out[9]: True

In [10]: "wouldn't" in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
Out[10]: True

In [11]: "should" in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
Out[11]: True

In [12]: "could" in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
Out[12]: False

In [13]: "would" in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
Out[13]: False
```

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a deliberate decision on the part of the compilers of the stopword list. The decision is probably related to (1) relative frequency of occurrence of these words in the corpus on which the list is based; and (2) the fact that the compilers of the list decided that it should consist of 2,400 words.

Comment: @BoarGules Hm... but from logical perspective it makes no sense, does it? "decided that it should consist of 2,400 words" >>> I didn't get this. Which list should consist of 2400 words? The stop words list is composed of 179 words currently.

Comment: According to the NLTK documentation the original stopword list was 2400 words for 11 languages compiled by *Porter et al*. No further reference, and I can't find it, I've looked. It may be that the 2400 was counted over all 11 languages and not just for English. If you want justification for the contents of the list then you need to ask the people over at nltk.org.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug per-se. What is and what is not considered a stopword will always be a little fuzzy. The people who made that list left out "should" for some reason - perhaps it was well founded, perhaps not - but regardless you should be able to add it in to the corpus for your own project and see if it provides better results for your task.

Regardless, this seems worth bringing up on their [github issues](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/).

Answer (score 2):

Oh actually this is very interesting!

Joel Nothman has once looked through the stopwords and found some disturbing results. See https://aclweb.org/anthology/papers/W/W18/W18-2502/

Agree with Ethan McCue, that this is definitely something that should be patched/resolved by bringing it up on NLTK's github issue tracker.